# Parallel SVN update process

Tags: linux, bash, svn

I need to execute several SVN update processes in background under same folder structure as I have many subfolders and want to speed up whole thing.

I have folder structure like this:

```
/folder/subfolder1/
/folder/subfolder2/
/folder/subfolder3/
...
/folder/subfolder1000/
```

I'm trying to do something like this in bash script:

```
svn up /folder/subfolder1 &
svn up /folder/subfolder2 &
svn up /folder/subfolder3 &
```

Problem is in that SVN complains that '/folder' is locked and only first task finish correct, other two don't and got error message like this:

```
svn: Working copy '/folder' locked
svn: run 'svn cleanup' to remove locks (type 'svn help cleanup' for details)
```

Is there a way to accomplish task on this way with several parallel SVN process because doing one by one folder (selected by some other process) takes a lot time to finish?

P.S: I'm doing all this in higher programing language (PHP-CLI) but for simplicity of question I write it as bash script (got same problem).

Comment: What is your `svn --version` ?

Comment: svn, version 1.6.11 (r934486)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In older versions of Subversion every subdirectory had its own `.svn` file. If your `svn` is old enough, and you run the commands in the subdirectories, then I think that won't lock the parent directory and the commands can succeed in parallel. Like this:

```
(cd /folder/subfolder1; svn up)&
(cd /folder/subfolder2; svn up)&
(cd /folder/subfolder3; svn up)&
```

Although, to be honest, I thought your original command should work too, I don't see why the parent directory gets locked.

Comment: It seams to work when cd-ing in subfolder! Will do some future testing and if works ok will accept your answer ;) Tnx a lot

Comment: I take an look in change log for this issue and seams that is related to this: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/subversion-commits/201007.mbox/%3C20100701193955.D574023889E7@eris.apache.org%3E "Teach the FSFS lock storage management code to consistently expect to
find in parent directory hashes not pointers to their immediate
children, but pointers to files locked anywhere below them."